# What is the data model used for tags and tag synonyms?

Tags: tags, synonym

I [asked this question on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104430/what-is-the-data-model-of-tag-synonyms), but i now realize that it may be more appropriate for the main site as it is a general question that would relate to any tagging based system (i am happy to close / delete one depending on where people think this question should go)

---

i have a similar system of tagged data and i am running into the same problem as SOF did where i have lots of tags that are really the same thing. I am trying to create a tag synonym page similar to SOF to support organizing this information.

A few questions around the relationships and "data model" of tag synonyms:

I assume that a master tag can have multiple synonym tags but a synonym tag can only be a 
synonym for one master tag. Is that correct?

Also, can a master tag also be a synonym tag? For example, lets say you have a tag called javascript and you had:

**Master**: js
**Synonyms**: java-script, js-web

can you also have:

**Master**: javascript
**Synonyms**: js

So in the example above, you would keep resolving to ultimately resolve **js-web** to **javascript** because the master tag: **js** is itself a synonym tag.

Also, that makes me think you could also run into a circular reference where you have a

**Master**: js
**Synonyms**: java-script

and

**Master**: javascript
**Synonyms**: js

How does the system deal with circular refernces?

Comment: Schemaless NoSQL DBs are flexible with this data model issues. Check out mongodb.org

Comment: loops and chains are kind of tricky ... this simplest thing to do is totally disallow loops and chains in the outset ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is tempting to give you a more theoretical answer on meta concerning folksonomies, polysemy and such!  Since I am answering on the StackOverflow side I will try and give a marginally more technical answer.  Running queries using the [StackOverflow Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) will allow me to attempt to answer your questions (I am not affiliated with StackOverflow so I can't know for sure).

On StackOverflow the master/synonym tag relationship is carefully [stewarded](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) and cultivated.  At the time of writing from the Data Explorer:

- Tags has 29488 rows
- TagSynonyms has 1916 rows

It is interesting to contrast this with other folksonomies, one article "[Technorati tags: Good idea, terrible implementation](https://intuitivestories.com/technorati_tags_good_idea_terrible_implementation.html)" states.

*"Technorati advertises that they're now tracking 466,951 different tags, which is pretty darn impressive when you consider that a typical dictionary has around 75,000 entries"*

A quick caveat, I usually write Oracle SQL and I assume that the Data Explorer is using SQLServer so my queries may be a little amateurish.  Firstly my presumptions about the data:

- anything listed in the Tags table is a "master tag".
- in the TagSynonyms table, TargetTagName is a "master tag", SourceTagName is the "synonym tag".

Now to your specific queries:

*"I assume that a master tag can have multiple synonym tags but a synonym tag can only be a synonym for one master tag. Is that correct?"*

```
select * from TagSynonyms where TargetTagName = 'javascript'
```

**Result:** Yes. A master tag can have multiple synonym tags.

```
select SourceTagName, count(*) from TagSynonyms group by SourceTagName having count(*) > 1
```

**Result:** Yes. A synonym tag can only be a synonym for one master tag.

*"Also, can a master tag also be a synonym tag?"*

```
select TagName from Tags
intersect
select SourceTagName from TagSynonyms
```

**Result:** Yes. A master tag can also be a synonym tag. When I ran this query there were 465 tags that were both synonym and master

*"How does the system deal with circular references?"*

This is where my logic/SQL may let me down. The question is can I find any circular references?  To do this I think I need to work out:

- Set a - set of tags that are both master and synonym
- Set b - synonyms for the synonyms of the tags in set a
- Set c - a intersection b

Anything in set c would be a circular reference.

We have already calculated set a above (it has 465 rows).

Set b - synonyms for the synonyms of set a

```
select SourceTagName from TagSynonyms where TargetTagName in (
select SourceTagName from TagSynonyms where TargetTagName in (
select TagName from Tags
intersect
select SourceTagName from TagSynonyms
))
```

**Result:** 0 rows

We can stop here, there is no point working out set c as we already know set b is empty.

Unless I got my logic or SQL wrong (which is very possible) it seems there are no circular references in StackOverflow.  I would imagine there are technical processes in place to prevent circular references from happening (otherwise StackOverflow could suffer StackOverflow!).